# BCH Coding: Parity Check Matrix

Tags: finite-fields, coding-theory

I was referring to a publication on BCH codes in GF(64) (http://ipnpr.jpl.nasa.gov/progress_report2/42-38/38O.PDF) where I noticed that the Parity Check Matrix (attached image) that they have derived is at first glance different from a parity check matrix of a standard (63, 56) BCH code.

My question is: How has this [Parity Check Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnPRQ.png) been derived?

Comment: What is this "standard" BCH code you compare this to? May be it uses a different primitive polynomial? $x^6+x+1$ is often used in place of its reciprocal $x^6+x^5+1$ as seems to have been the case in that JPL paper (if I got it right). But the resulting code is a BCH code in both cases - they just use a different primitive element.